# A particular SVG file is not printable using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I can't generate PDF for this particular SVG file from wkhtmltopdf.

Can anybody tell me why?

I can view and print it from chrome perfectly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2SWQPqbIKKQWFc1bkV6Z0hQLVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No idea.  You could try loading it into Inkscape and saving as "Optimised SVG". Otherwise you may need to go through the XML and remove parts systematically until you find the element that is causing wkhtmltopdf to fail.

Comment: I saved it as optimized SVG. Still not working. But it is working in chrome and it is correctly printing via chromes print option.

Comment: Bear in mind that Chrome no longer uses the webkit engine. It uses a fork of it. So you may be striking a bug with the SVG rendering that has been fixed in Chrome, but not webkit.  You may have more luck finding a solution if you report the bug to the wkhtmltopdf folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the height and width percentage to exact pixel values.

--Thanks to my boss Jayan.